Encountered wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format
Getting following exception when running component test.
Environment setup:

JDK 17
jakarta.jms:jakarta.jms-api:3.1.0
OS: Windows WSL
Docker: activemq:latest running on Rancher Desktop

build.gradle
org.apache.activemq:activemq-client:6.1.1
application.yml
csiReceiving:
  responseQueue: ${queue.csi.receiving.response}
  mqserver: ${queue.csi.receiving.mqserver}
  localQueueProtocol: tcp://
  localQueueHost: 192.168.208.1
  localQueuePort: 61616

application-test.yml
   queue:
      csi:
        primary:
          endpoint: activemq
          destination: Queue.Request
          response: Queue.Reply
        secondary:
          endpoint: activemq
          destination: Queue.RequestGpp
          response: Queue.ReplyGpp
        receiving:
          response: Queue.ReplyDp
          mqserver: local

Exception:
2024-08-07 18:42:37.709  INFO 44320 --- [Test worker] [CID:] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 4.6.0 (camel-12) started in 150ms (build:0ms init:0ms start:150ms)
2024-08-07 18:42:37.740  INFO 44320 --- [Test worker] [CID:] c.n.e.s.c.stubs.CamelContextWrapper      : Camel context DataPower created
2024-08-07 18:42:37.826  INFO 44320 --- [Test worker] [CID:] o.a.camel.language.xpath.XPathBuilder    : Created default XPathFactory com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathFactoryImpl@6682c2c0
2024-08-07 18:42:37.913  INFO 44320 --- [Test worker] [CID:] o.a.c.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext   : Apache Camel 4.6.0 (camel-13) is starting
2024-08-07 18:42:38.459  INFO 44320 --- [ActiveMQ Task-1] [CID:] o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport       : Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:61616
2024-08-07 18:42:43.889 DEBUG 44320 --- [CustomerProfilePool housekeeper] [CID:] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : CustomerProfilePool - Pool stats (total=7, active=0, idle=7, waiting=0)
2024-08-07 18:42:43.889 DEBUG 44320 --- [CustomerProfilePool housekeeper] [CID:] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : CustomerProfilePool - Fill pool skipped, pool has sufficient level or currently being filled (queueDepth=0).
2024-08-07 18:42:48.470  WARN 44320 --- [Test worker] [CID:] o.a.a.t.failover.FailoverTransport       : Transport (tcp://localhost:61616) failed, attempting to automatically reconnect

java.io.IOException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format.
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator.oneway(WireFormatNegotiator.java:99)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport.oneway(FailoverTransport.java:670)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.MutexTransport.oneway(MutexTransport.java:68)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.asyncRequest(ResponseCorrelator.java:81)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:86)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1454)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.ensureConnectionInfoSent(ActiveMQConnection.java:1548)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.start(ActiveMQConnection.java:568)


@JustinBertram it is apache ActiveMQ

@JustinBertram update the question with activeMQ version and yml config

As far as I can tell you're only providing details about the client. You still have not provided details about what version of ActiveMQ you're using on the broker or how the broker is configured.
